# How do I get rid of centurylink search in firefox?

Tags: firefox

Im using ubuntu 10 and the  firefox 10.0.
When using the address bar to search, when i type long words like 'search this in google' the search defaults to google. But when i type in small words like 'search' the browser uses centurylink. Please let me know how to get rid of this and make google as default search engine.

Comment: When you get the CenturyLink results, click the preferences/settings/gear-icon link in the upper right (as of Oct 2019), turn off the setting, and click save. Then it will stop hijacking your search.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer that works for me:  There is a spot on mine (mac OS) that says in faded letters "why am I here" or "why do I see this".  I clicked it, and there was a place to click to disable Centruylink searches.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

From the **Navigation Toolbar** in search box select your favourite Search engine through this menu .

[image]

Or select the `manage search Engines..` option to **remove** the Desired Search engine as from the image.

[image]

Comment: Hi I could not find any CenturuLink search in the options to remove

Comment: @user1455116- To change the internet keyword search follow this link http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-web-address-bar

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that this is being done by centurylink (your isp) in response to failed DNS queries.

Without changing browsers you will be unable to fix this problem. However I do know that most versions of Chrome/Chromium will do some stuff to avoid this problem and, I believe, so does more recent versions of firefox.

Comment: on my windows system I'm using firefox 14.0.1 and still see the same problem. I do not want the search to redirect to CenturyLink

Comment: Well in that case you can try using chromium/chrome which does some magic to avoid this problem entirely. Otherwise adding a space before or after the search term might avoid the problem.